# SlideDown or SlideUp effect to set Height

Tags: jquery

How can I do a `slideDown()` or `slideUp()` effect but I don't want close my `div`, I want just set the `height` but doing the `slideDown()` or `slideUp()` effect.

**Example**

```
<div id="modalNovoTicket" style="height: 600px;"></div>

$("#modalNovoTicket").slideUp("slow", function () {
    $(this).css("height", "400px");
});
```

**Problem**

With this code, my `div` close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$("#modalNovoTicket").animate({
    'height': '500px'
}, 500);
```

Comment: You should pass a numeric value through rather than a string

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik It isn't required according to the jQuery animate documentation

Comment: @Sam I think it is a good practice to use complete values for properties that have multiple types. Now the height can be `em`, `px` or `%`. So I prefer to give the type (`"height": "72px"`). On the other hand, for properties that don't have multiple types I give simple values `z-index:3`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `animate()` method.

```
$(...).animate({ height: 400 }, "slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use animate:

```
$("#modalNovoTicket").animate({height:400},"slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

try this code

```
$("#modalNovoTicket").animate({
    height: 400
}, 600)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.animate()` method and for delay use `600` for `slow` speed, `400` for medium speed and `200` for fast speed. Here the delay time will be measured in milliseconds.

```
 $("#modalNovoTicket").animate({
        height: "400px"
    }, 600);
```

Comment: @Lucas_Santos is that make a sense?

Answer (score -1):

Use [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead:

```
$("#modalNovoTicket").animate({
  height: "400px"
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/P4qTA/).

You can also specify an animation speed by integer (in milliseconds) or string (`"slow"`, `"fast"`):

```
$("#modalNovoTicket").animate({
  height: "400px"
}, 500);
```

And a block of code to execute once the animation is complete:

```
$("#modalNovoTicket").animate({
  height: "400px"
}, 500, function() {
  alert("Animation complete!");
});
```

Comment: You should pass a numeric value through rather than a string.

Comment: I didnt say it couldnt be used. The jQuery animate method specifically states -> Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified

Comment: @Sam therefore "I didnt say it couldnt be used" != true